# Why ElasticSearch triggers refresh more often than refresh_interval

Tags: elasticsearch

As far as I understand ElasticSearch documentation, `refresh` happens once per `refresh_interval` or when the indexing buffer is full.

My environent:

- An index, 8 hards 1 replica, with `"refresh_interval" : "3600s"`.
- The cluster is 3 nodes 58Gb of RAM each.

So, `refresh_interval` is one hour and, with default settings, there's more than 5Gb of indexing buffer for each node.

But when I check my admin console, I see this:

[image]

Indexing rate is almost 0, but refresh is triggered frequently.

The idea idea is to have a huge `refresh_interval` to utilize caching for heavy aggregations that we run on this index. But the cache doesn't live long enough.

Comment: "almost 0" means there are still indexing tasks going on. Are you sure that your indexing requests don't trigger refresh at the same time?

Comment: @Val Yes, you can see on the `Request Rate` chart - there're some indexing requests going on. But, per my understanding, it should be thousands of requests until it overflows the 5Gb indexing buffer.

Comment: Thanks, but can you also answer my second question? How are you indexing and are you sure than nothing triggers explicit refreshes after each indexing operation?

Comment: @Val confirmed with the team - we don't use `_refresh` anywhere in the project.